# An explicit value for the identity column in table can only be specified when a column list is used and IDENTITY_INSERT is ON SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to do this query

```
INSERT INTO dbo.tbl_A_archive
  SELECT *
  FROM SERVER0031.DB.dbo.tbl_A
```

but even after I ran

```
set identity_insert dbo.tbl_A_archive on
```

I am getting this error message

> An explicit value for the identity column in table 'dbo.tbl_A_archive' can only be specified when a column list is used and IDENTITY_INSERT is ON.

`tbl_A` is a huge table in rows and width, i.e. it has a LOT of columns. I do not want to have to type all the columns out manually. How can I get this to work?

Comment: i have already setup a linked server by the way!

Comment: i'm having this problem as well, except the "insert into X select * Y" wasn't a problem until i changed the table schema

Answer (score 192, accepted):

**Summary**

SQL Server won't let you insert an explicit value in an identity column unless you use a column list. Thus, you have the following options:

1. Make a column list (either manually or using tools, see below)

OR

2. make the identity column in `tbl_A_archive` a regular, *non-identity* column: If your table is an archive table and you always specify an explicit value for the identity column, why do you even need an identity column? Just use a regular int instead.

---

**Details on Solution 1**

Instead of

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT archive_table ON;

INSERT INTO archive_table
  SELECT *
  FROM source_table;

SET IDENTITY_INSERT archive_table OFF;
```

you need to write

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT archive_table ON;

INSERT INTO archive_table (field1, field2, ...)
  SELECT field1, field2, ...
  FROM source_table;

SET IDENTITY_INSERT archive_table OFF;
```

with `field1, field2, ...` containing the names of all columns in your tables. If you want to auto-generate that list of columns, have a look at [Dave's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2005474/87698) or [Andomar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2005527/87698).

---

**Details on Solution 2**

Unfortunately, it is not possible to just "change the type" of an identity int column to a non-identity int column. Basically, you have the following options:

- If the archive table does not contain data yet, drop the column and add a new one without identity.

OR

- Use SQL Server Management Studio to set the `Identity Specification`/`(Is Identity)` property of the identity column in your archive table to `No`. Behind the scenes, this will create a script to re-create the table and copy existing data, so, to do that, you will also need to unset `Tools`/`Options`/`Designers`/`Table and Database Designers`/`Prevent saving changes that require table re-creation`.

OR

- Use one of the workarounds described in this answer: [Remove Identity from a column in a table](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8230257/87698)

Comment: To your bottom solution:
If the column has "IDENTITY (1, 1)" or something like this, he will need to remove it temporary too.

Comment: @AleksandrKhomenko: Yes, that's what I meant by *"make [it] a regular (**non-identity**) int column"*.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I meant actually that he will need to remove the **auto-increment** property too. In the case of SQL-Server it calls "IDENTITY (1, 1)" - your answer is absolutely right. But MySQL and Oracle has another commands for it (and it gets non-obvious, please look at http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_autoincrement.asp)

Comment: This is lacking in detail. I understand it may be rote to some but it is nonsense to others

Comment: Someone please elaborate how to do either of these.

Comment: @DJ.: I have added some detail.

Comment: Saying things like "Well, the error message basically says it all" hasn't ever helped anybody in the entire history of programming. If the error message was understandable then nobody would bother creating a question on Stackoverflow.

Comment: @metabuddy: That does not match my personal experience: I *regularly* have support cases where a client (including developers) calls "because they get an error message". After asking them to reproduce the problem and reading the message to them aloud (with a slight rephrasing, because I don't want them to feel stupid), their problem is solved, because the error message contained all the information they needed. That having been said, I answered this question over 10 years ago, and I agree that a more diplomatic tone wouldn't hurt. I'll change it.

Answer (score 389):

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT tableA ON
```

You have to make a column list for your INSERT statement:

```
INSERT Into tableA ([id], [c2], [c3], [c4], [c5] ) 
SELECT [id], [c2], [c3], [c4], [c5] FROM tableB
```

not like "INSERT Into tableA SELECT ........"

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT tableA OFF
```

Comment: +1 ... You only need explicit columns in the SELECT clause of the query.  You can keep an asterisk in the INSERT clause of the query

Comment: ... unless the target has an identity column, and the source table does not have an identity column

Comment: this answer is a bit more clear than Heinzi because it mentions SET IDENTITY_INSERT

Comment: +1 Works like a charm!
However, "You can keep an asterisk in the INSERT clause of the query" won't work here.

Comment: I got this error when the columns in select clause didn't match with the destination table. Making sure of this, the insert worked for me

Comment: oh thank you.  The answer was that one needs to explicitly list the columns!!! I didn't realize SELECT * doesn't work.  You should probably put that in Bold  :-D

Answer (score 50):

If you're using SQL Server Management Studio, you don't have to type the column list yourself - just right-click the table in *Object Explorer* and choose **Script Table as** -> **SELECT to** -> **New Query Editor Window**.

If you aren't, then a query similar to this should help as a starting point:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(
    (SELECT ', ' + QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME)
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
        WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'tbl_A'
        ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION
        FOR XML path('')),
    3,
    200000);
```

Comment: This can be selected into a variable and used in dynamic SQL query. You saved my day. Thanks a lot!

Comment: thanks! I made this with it https://gist.github.com/timabell/0ddd6a69565593f907c7

Comment: wow. i was desperetaly looking for this to build my query dynamically. Surprised to see this here. Thanks mate.

Answer (score 34):

Agree with Heinzi's answer.  For first second option, here's a query that generates a comma-separated list of columns in a table:

```
select name + ', ' as [text()] 
from sys.columns 
where object_id = object_id('YourTable') 
for xml path('')
```

For big tables, this can save a lot of typing work :)

Comment: @Thanks, really helpful. :)

Comment: Sometimes you just need a pragmatic solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 17):

If the "archive" table is meant to be an exact copy of you main table then I would just suggest that you remove the fact that the id is an identiy column. That way it will let you insert them.

Alternatively you can allow and the disallow identity inserts for the table with the following statement

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT tbl_A_archive ON
--Your inserts here
SET IDENTITY_INSERT tbl_A_archive OFF
```

Finally, if you need the identity column to work as is then you can always just run the stored proc.

```
sp_columns tbl_A_archive
```

This will return you all of the columns from the table which you can then cut and paste into your query. (This is almost ALWAYS better than using a *)

Answer (score 13):

For the SQL statement, you also have to specify the column list. For eg.

```
INSERT INTO tbl (idcol1,col2) VALUES ( value1,value2)
```

instead of

```
INSERT INTO tbl VALUES ( value1,value2)
```

Comment: This is not the case for the OP's statement. VALUES is not requires if INSERT INTO is followed by a SELECT statement. Please revise or remove your answer.

Answer (score 8):

Both will work but if you still get error by using #1 then go for #2

1)

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT customers ON
GO
insert into dbo.tbl_A_archive(id, ...)
SELECT Id, ...
FROM SERVER0031.DB.dbo.tbl_A
```

2)

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT customers ON
GO
insert into dbo.tbl_A_archive(id, ...)
VALUES(@Id,....)
```

Comment: This really isn't the way to go if the OP is inserting multiple records. You are ignoring "tbl_A is a huge table in rows and width, i.e. it has a LOT of columns. I do not want to have to type all the columns out manually."

Answer (score 4):

In order to populate all of the column names into a comma-delimited list for a Select statement for the solutions mentioned for this question, I use the following options as they are a little less verbose than most responses here. Although, most responses here are still perfectly acceptable, however.

**1)**

```
SELECT column_name + ',' 
FROM   information_schema.columns 
WHERE  table_name = 'YourTable'
```

**2)** This is probably the simplest approach to creating columns,
if you have SQL Server SSMS.

> 1) Go to the table in Object Explorer and click on the + to the left of the table name or double-click the table name to open the sub list.
>
> 2) Drag the column subfolder over to the main query area and it will autopaste the entire column list for you.

Answer (score 4):

You must need to specify columns name which you want to insert if there is an Identity column. 
So the command will be like this below:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT DuplicateTable ON

INSERT Into DuplicateTable ([IdentityColumn], [Column2], [Column3], [Column4] ) 
SELECT [IdentityColumn], [Column2], [Column3], [Column4] FROM MainTable

SET IDENTITY_INSERT DuplicateTable OFF
```

If your table has many columns then get those columns name by using this command.

```
SELECT column_name + ','
FROM   information_schema.columns 
WHERE  table_name = 'TableName'
for xml path('')
```

(after removing the last comma(',')) Just copy past columns name.

Answer (score 4):

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT tableA ON

INSERT Into tableA ([id], [c2], [c3], [c4], [c5] ) 
SELECT [id], [c2], [c3], [c4], [c5] FROM tableB
```

Not like this

```
INSERT INTO tableA
SELECT * FROM tableB

SET IDENTITY_INSERT tableA OFF
```

Answer (score 3):

This should work. I just ran into your issue:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.tbl_A_archive ON;
INSERT INTO     dbo.tbl_A_archive (IdColumn,OtherColumn1,OtherColumn2,...)
SELECT  *
FROM        SERVER0031.DB.dbo.tbl_A;
SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.tbl_A_archive OFF;
```

Unfortunately it seems you do need a list of the columns including the identity column to insert records which specify the Identity. **However**, you don't HAVE to list the columns in the SELECT.
As *@Dave Cluderay* suggested this will result in a formatted list for you to copy and paste (if less than 200000 characters).

I added the USE since I'm switching between instances.

```
USE PES
SELECT SUBSTRING(
    (SELECT ', ' + QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME)
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
        WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Provider'
        ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION
        FOR XML path('')),
    3,
    200000);
```

Answer (score 2):

This code snippet shows how to insert into table when identity Primary Key column is ON.

```sql
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Roles] ON
GO
insert into Roles (Id,Name) values(1,'Admin')
GO
insert into Roles (Id,Name) values(2,'User')
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Roles] OFF
GO
```

Answer (score 2):

Please make sure that the column names, data types, and order in the table from where you are selecting records is exactly same as the destination table. Only difference should be that destination table has an identity column as the first column, that is not there in source table.

I was facing similar issue when I was executing "INSERT INTO table_Dest SELECT * FROM table_source_linked_server_excel".  The tables had 115 columns.

I had two such tables where I was loading data from Excel (As linked server) into tables in database. In database tables, I had added an identity column called 'id' that was not there in source Excel. For one table the query was running successfully and in another I got the error "An explicit value for the identity column in table can only be specified when a column list is used and IDENTITY_INSERT is ON SQL Server". This was puzzling as the scenario was exactly same for both the queries. So I investigated into this and what I found was that in the query where I was getting error with INSERT INTO .. SELECT *:

1. Some of the column names in source table were modified, though values were correct
2. There were some extra columns beyond actual data columns that were being selected by SELECT *. I discovered this by using the option of "Script table as > Select to > new query window" on the source Excel table (under linked servers).  There was one hidden column just after the last column in Excel, though it did not have any data. I deleted that column in source Excel table and saved it.

After making the above two changes the query for INSERT INTO... SELECT * ran successfully. The identity column in destination table generated identity values for each inserted row as expected.

So, even though the destination table may have an identity column that is not there in source table, the INSERT INTO.. SELECT * will run successfully if the names, data types, and column order in source and destination are exactly the same.

Hope it helps someone.

Comment: Just for the effort I give you 1UP

Answer (score 1):

For if you want to insert your values from one table to another through a stored procedure. I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39416645/558211) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39414555/558211), the latter which is almost like Andomar's answer.

```
CREATE procedure [dbo].[RealTableMergeFromTemp]
    with execute as owner
AS
BEGIN
BEGIN TRANSACTION RealTableDataMerge
SET XACT_ABORT ON

    DECLARE @columnNameList nvarchar(MAX) =
     STUFF((select ',' + a.name
      from sys.all_columns a
      join sys.tables t on a.object_id = t.object_id 
       where t.object_id = object_id('[dbo].[RealTable]') 
    order by a.column_id
    for xml path ('')
    ),1,1,'')

    DECLARE @SQLCMD nvarchar(MAX) =N'INSERT INTO [dbo].[RealTable] (' + @columnNameList + N') SELECT * FROM [#Temp]'

    SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[RealTable] ON;
    exec(@sqlcmd)
    SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[RealTable] OFF

COMMIT TRANSACTION RealTableDataMerge
END

GO
```

Answer (score 1):

> "an explicit value for the identity column in table can only be
> specified when ..."

What fixed it for me, was not specifying the identity column.

So instead of

```
INSERT INTO dbo.tbl_A_archive
  SELECT *
 FROM SERVER0031.DB.dbo.tbl_A
```

I specified all columns but not the identity one (tbl_A_archive.ID)

```
INSERT INTO dbo.tbl_A_archive
  SELECT col1, col2, colETC
 FROM SERVER0031.DB.dbo.tbl_A
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this error occurs due to the mismatch with number of columns in table definition and number of columns in the insert query. Also the length of the column is omitted with the entered value.
So just review the table definition to resolve this issue

Comment: Worked for me: I forgot to add a column to the table from the design, good thing to check for this first before trying other answers.

Answer (score 0):

There is one or more column that has auto-increment property or the value of that attribute will be calculated as constraints. You are trying to modify that column.

There is two way to solve it
1) Mention other columns explicitly and set their values only and the PrimaryKey or the auto-increment column value will set automatically.

2) You can turn on INDENTITY_INSERT then execute your insert query finally turn off IDENTITY_INSERT.

Suggestion: Follow the first step because it is a more suitable and efficient approach.

For more information read [this article on SQL-helper](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/error-messages/msg-8101.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I use the following to create a temp exact as the table but without the identity:

```
SELECT TOP 0 CONVERT(INT,0)myid,* INTO #temp FROM originaltable

ALTER TABLE #temp DROP COLUMN id

EXEC tempdb.sys.sp_rename N'#temp.myid', N'id', N'COLUMN'
```

Gets a warning about renames but no big deal.
I use this on production class systems. Helps make sure the copy will follow any future table modifications and the temp produced is capable of getting rows additional times within a task. Please note that the PK constraint is also removed - if you need it you can add it at the end.