# Set IDENTITY_INSERT ON is not working

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I want to copy a table `Equipment` from one database `MyDBQA` to our test database `MyDB`. There is an identity column in the table which is the primary key (int, not null).

But I got an error:

> Msg 8101, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>   An explicit value for the identity column in table 'MyDB.dbo.Equipment' can only be specified when a column list is used
>   and IDENTITY_INSERT is ON.

My script:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [MyDB].[dbo].[Equipment] ON
INSERT INTO [MyDB].[dbo].[Equipment]  SELECT * FROM [MyDBQA].[dbo].[Equipment]
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [MyDB].[dbo].[Equipment] OFF
```

Comment: "when a column list is used **AND** ..."

Comment: Possible duplicate of [An explicit value for the identity column in table can only be specified when a column list is used and IDENTITY\_INSERT is ON SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2005437/an-explicit-value-for-the-identity-column-in-table-can-only-be-specified-when-a)

Comment: have an answer here please see [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2005437/an-explicit-value-for-the-identity-column-in-table-can-only-be-specified-when-a/46108888#46108888)

Answer (score 114, accepted):

You might be just missing the column list, as the message says

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [MyDB].[dbo].[Equipment] ON

INSERT INTO [MyDB].[dbo].[Equipment]
            (COL1,
             COL2)
SELECT COL1,
       COL2
FROM   [MyDBQA].[dbo].[Equipment]

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [MyDB].[dbo].[Equipment] OFF
```

Answer (score 19):

The relevant part of the error message is

```
...when a column list is used...
```

You are not using a column list, you are using `SELECT *`. Use a column list instead:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [MyDB].[dbo].[Equipment] ON 

INSERT INTO [MyDB].[dbo].[Equipment] (Col1, Col2, ...)
SELECT Col1, Col2, ... FROM [MyDBQA].[dbo].[Equipment] 

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [MyDB].[dbo].[Equipment] OFF
```

Comment: Can Col1 be the identity column?

Comment: Yes. *(10 more chars required)*

Answer (score 4):

In VB code, when trying to submit an `INSERT` query, you must submit a double query in the same 'executenonquery' like this:

```
sqlQuery = "SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.TheTable ON; INSERT INTO dbo.TheTable (Col1, COl2) VALUES (Val1, Val2); SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.TheTable OFF;"
```

I used a `;` separator instead of a GO.

Works for me. Late but efficient!

Comment: Dude, you don't even know HOW MUCH you've helped me with this one!! It's not VB, but Node.js and I tried transactions, using GO, but none of this helped... Thanks for finally helping me after looking for 3 hours!

Comment: This is the answer to my problem as well! Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Here's Microsoft's write up on using SET IDENTITY_INSERT, which might be helpful to others seeing this post if they, like me, found this post when trying to recreate deleted records while maintaining the original identity column value.

to recreate deleted records with original identity column value:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259221(v=sql.80).aspx