# Case-Sensitive Linked-Server merge script - Set IDENTITY_INSERT <table> ON not working

Tags: t-sql, merge, identity, openquery

I am doing a experimental script to do a SQL Comparison (`COLLATED` as case-sensitive) and I am having issues with the `SET IDENTITY_INSERT <Table> ON`

I have switched on this option and disabled foreign key checks, but it still seems to be complaining about the latter.

Here are the steps I followed:

1 - I created a linked server

```
EXEC sp_addlinkedserver @Server=N'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx', @srvproduct=N'SQL Server'
```

2 - I added the login credentials

```
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedsrvlogin 
@rmtsrvname = N'xxx.xxx.xxxx.xxx', 
@locallogin = NULL , 
@useself = N'False',
@rmtuser = N'xxxxxxxxxxx',
@rmtpassword = N'xxxxxxxxxxx'
```

3 - In the same batch, I set the `identity_insert`, disabled foreign key checks and ran the following merge script. Note, the deferred query returns an `XML` field which is disallowed over distributed servers, so I casted to `NVARCHAR(MAX)`

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [DATABASE1].[dbo].[TABLE1] ON
ALTER TABLE [DATABASE1].[dbo].[TABLE1] NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL

MERGE [DATABASE1].[dbo].[TABLE1]
USING OPENQUERY([xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx], 'SELECT S.ID, S.EventId, S.SnapshotTypeID, CAST(S.Content AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS Content FROM [DATABASE1].[dbo].[TABLE1] AS S') AS S
ON (CAST([DATABASE1].[dbo].[TABLE1].Content AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) = S.Content)
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET
    THEN INSERT VALUES (S.ID, S.EventId, S.SnapshotTypeID, CAST(S.Content AS XML))
WHEN MATCHED 
    THEN UPDATE SET [DATABASE1].[dbo].[TABLE1].EventId = S.EventId,
                    [DATABASE1].[dbo].[TABLE1].SnapshotTypeID = S.SnapshotTypeID,
                    [DATABASE1].[dbo].[TABLE1].Content = S.Content
COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS;
GO
```

The error message I am getting reads as follows:

> Msg 8101, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
>   An explicit value for the identity column in table 'Database1.dbo.Table' can only be specified when a column list is used and IDENTITY_INSERT is ON.

How can I fix this? As I mentioned, this script is only an experiment for one of the systems I am writing. I am probably reinventing the wheel somewhere, but its all about learning in this exercise.

Comment: This script is a comparison script which reads data from a table on a remote server, and inserts / updates it into a table which schema is identical on my local. The problems here are three-fold

1- When you used a linked server (the remote server), any and all XML fields needs to be converted first, else you get an error. So OpenQuery's result set acts as my source.

2- Conversion slows down the query a lot.

3- The merge statement doesn't run at all because it is complaining about the `SET IDENTITY_INSERT <tablename> ON` - Which is what I am trying **to solve in this question**.

Comment: There are tools out there to do the job, but as I mentioned a few times, this script is supposed to be experimental

Comment: when a column list is used - you have no column list

Comment: I see what you meant there Blam. Let me add a column list - did not think about that

Comment: @Blam You solved it. Add your answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Set IDENTITY\_INSERT ON is not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12006273/set-identity-insert-on-is-not-working)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An explicit value for the identity column in table 'Database1.dbo.Table' can only be specified when a column list is used and IDENTITY_INSERT is ON.

You have no column list

Comment: I know about this. I feel like a brick for forgetting that during scripting. I should read my errors more ><