# An explicit value for the identity column in table 'COM_MST' can only be specified when a column list is used and IDENTITY_INSERT is ON

Tags: sql-server, identity

don't know why this code is not executing...

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT COM_MST ON
GO
INSERT INTO COM_MST 
SELECT * FROM COM_MST_DEL
```

and showing an error

```
An explicit value for the identity column in table 'COM_MST' can only be specified when a column list is used and IDENTITY_INSERT is ON.
```

Comment: I'm always amazed that people don't spot the *and* in the middle of the error message and realize that there are *two* conditions that they have to fulfill.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to specify the columns in the insert statement

Answer (score 1):

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT COM_MST ON
GO
INSERT INTO COM_MST 
SELECT * FROM COM_MST_DEL
```

In this your select statement `SELECT * FROM COM_MST_DEL` might be returning more than the column available in table  `COM_MST` also make sure to specify the column name in `Insert` statement.

OR

See the solution proposed in the post [An explicit value for the identity column in table can only be specified when a column list is used and IDENTITY_INSERT is ON SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2005437/an-explicit-value-for-the-identity-column-in-table-can-only-be-specified-when-a#2005474)