# Can't copy table from one SQL Server database to another, get identity_insert error (but it is on)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to copy certain rows from one table to another. The tables are identical in format, but one is missing some records. This is the error message I am getting:

"An explicit value for the identity column in table 'dbo.table' can only be specified when a column list is used and IDENTITY_INSERT is ON."

The thing is, is that I am using a column list, and IDENTITY_INSERT is on. I've confirmed this by inserting a row into the target table and specifying the identify column. It worked fine. I've looked for everything I can find on how to do this, and everything I have found says my syntax is fine. Here is my code:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.table ON
GO
INSERT 
INTO dbo.table 
SELECT [IDcol], [col2], etc.
FROM database.dbo.table
WHERE stuff
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.table OFF
```

So that generated an error. However, this worked just fine:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.table ON
GO
INSERT INTO dbo.table (IDcol, col2) 
VALUES (155555555, 0)
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.table OFF
```

Any ideas? I need to use the same identity values, so letting them be incremented during the insert is not an option. I am using SQL Server 2005. Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: **when a column list is used** applies to the insert not the `SELECT`. Your first query should begin `INSERT INTO dbo.table (IDcol, col2)`

Comment: possible duplicate of [An explicit value for the identity column in table can only be specified when a column list is used and IDENTITY\_INSERT is ON SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2005437/an-explicit-value-for-the-identity-column-in-table-can-only-be-specified-when-a)

Comment: Wow, that was fast. Thank you, Martin Smith. I've been banging my head against the wall for an hour. Can't believe I missed that- I was sure my syntax was correct! I think one problem was that I was so focused on the identity_insert part of the error message. Can you put your comment into an answer so that I can select it?