# How do I insert data into a row in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-insert, identity-insert

I am following a tutorial and learning MVC from a book, where I was told to create a table using this script, which I did. But now I want to add an entire row to my Pet table, but I am unable to do it.

Script used to create all my tables.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Setting] (
    [Id] INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1)
    ,[Key] VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
    ,[Value] VARCHAR(500) NULL
    ,CONSTRAINT [PK_Setting] PRIMARY KEY ([Id])
    );

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PetType] (
    [PetTypeID] INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1)
    ,[PetTypeDescription] VARCHAR(50) NULL
    ,CONSTRAINT [PK_PetType] PRIMARY KEY ([PetTypeID])
    );

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Status] (
    [StatusID] INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1)
    ,[Description] VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
    ,CONSTRAINT [PK_Status] PRIMARY KEY ([StatusID])
    );

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Pet] (
    [PetID] INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1)
    ,[PetName] VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
    ,[PetAgeYears] INT NULL
    ,[PetAgeMonths] INT NULL
    ,[StatusID] INT NOT NULL
    ,[LastSeenOn] DATE NULL
    ,[LastSeenWhere] VARCHAR(500) NULL
    ,[Notes] VARCHAR(1500) NULL
    ,[UserId] INT NOT NULL
    ,CONSTRAINT [PK_Pet] PRIMARY KEY ([PetID])
    ,CONSTRAINT [FK_Pet_Status] FOREIGN KEY ([StatusID]) REFERENCES [Status]([StatusID])
    ,CONSTRAINT [FK_Pet_User] FOREIGN KEY ([UserId]) REFERENCES [UserProfile]([UserId])
    );

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PetPhoto] (
    [PhotoID] INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1)
    ,[PetID] INT NOT NULL
    ,[Photo] VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_PhotoFile] DEFAULT '/content/pets/no-image.png'
    ,[Notes] VARCHAR(500) NULL
    ,CONSTRAINT [PK_PetPhoto] PRIMARY KEY ([PhotoID])
    ,CONSTRAINT [FK_PetPhoto_Pet] FOREIGN KEY ([PetID]) REFERENCES [Pet]([PetID])
    );

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Message] (
    [MessageID] INT NOT NULL
    ,[UserId] INT NOT NULL
    ,[MessageDate] DATETIME NOT NULL
    ,[From] VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL
    ,[Email] VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL
    ,[Subject] VARCHAR(150) NULL
    ,[Message] VARCHAR(1500) NOT NULL
    ,CONSTRAINT [PK_Message] PRIMARY KEY ([MessageID])
    ,CONSTRAINT [FK_Message_User] FOREIGN KEY ([UserId]) REFERENCES [UserProfile]([UserId])
    );
```

I want to add some random values(for testing) into my Pet table's first row.
This is the Pet table's first row as an image for further clarity.

[image]

I tried using this script to add values to my table.

```
INSERT INTO Pet VALUES ('1', 'Fido', '12', '4', '1', '12/07/2004', 'New York', 'nothing', '1')
```

But I got an error saying

> An explicit value for the identity column in table 'Pet' can only be specified when a column list is used and IDENTITY_INSERT is ON.

Now I am fairly new to SQL and I am unable to figure this out. I looked at other SO answers where people said something about `SET IDENTITY_INSERT`, but this didn't work for me as well. I believe I misunderstood other SO answer since I am fairly new to database languages. So need your help.

Thanks

Comment: `[PetID]` column is an `identity` column. And you are trying to insert data to that column also. Just remove it.

Comment: u need not insert data in Identy column

Comment: Possible duplicate of [An explicit value for the identity column in table can only be specified when a column list is used and IDENTITY\_INSERT is ON SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2005437/an-explicit-value-for-the-identity-column-in-table-can-only-be-specified-when-a)

Comment: Oh I see. That makes sense. So I removed the value of 1 in my INSERT statement and I got another error. "The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Pet_Status". The conflict occurred in database "aspnet-HaveYouSeenMe-20160720053115", table "dbo.Status", column 'StatusID'.
The statement has been terminated."

Comment: If you're following a tutorial then I would suggest following the steps in order...

Comment: The error that you are encountering are very common, you should do a little bit of research

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQL Server **identity** is used for **autoincrement**. identity(1,1) means the starting value for the column will be 1 and will be incremented by 1. You can change it to desired value for example identity(5,2) starts the value at 5 and increments by 2. You no need to specify an explicit value for setting this column, it will be automatically assigned a unique value.

In mysql you can use AUTO_INCREMENT

Refer w3schools page for details [sql autoincrement](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_autoincrement.asp)

Answer (score 2):

PetID is defined as IDENTITY so you cannot specify a value to INSERT in that column unless you set "IDENTITY_INSERT" option to ON.

You have two options:

- Dont specify that column/value and let SQL generate it for you.
- Set  IDENTITY_INSERT to ON before your INSERT operation.

Answer (score 0):

Another very cool way to add rows/edit table (including editting deleting rows) is to use Microsoft SQL Management Studio Express. I didn't know about this until I'd been learning SQL for years. Basically expand the tree structure to the left, right-click on a table and choose Edit Table.  When you get going with SQL more, you can edit Stored Procedures in here and pretty much anything SQL else you can can think of.

I've blurred out the actual database names but this gives you the gist of it :-

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I was using Visual Studio for my project and tried to look if I could so something like this by clicking anywhere, but could not find anything like this in Visual Studio. I initially wanted to do everything SQL-related in SQL Server Management Studio itself, but had trouble installing it, so I just went ahead with what was there in Visual Studio.

Comment: Personally I find that unless you are inserting rows every day then I always have to look up the sql command every time. But I find that learning the UPDATE command is more memorable. There is no way to reverse an UPDATE though unless you went back to backup so also learn about the BEGIN ROLLBACK so you get an idea of how many rows you will be affecting before you commit an UPDATE.