# SQL IDENTITY INSERT Issue

Tags: sql-server

Can you please help.

I am running the following query:

```
set identity_insert sites_dynamic ON 

insert into sites_dynamic
    select * 
    from gpbatt_archive.dbo.sites_dynamic 
    where site_serial_number = 49955

set identity_insert sites_dynamic OFF 

set identity_insert sites_static ON 

insert into sites_static
    select * 
    from gpbatt_archive.dbo.sites_static 
    where static_site_id in (select static_site_id 
                             from gpbatt_archive.dbo.sites_dynamic 
                             where site_serial_number = 49955)

set identity_insert sites_static OFF
```

Error returned is:

> Msg 8101, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
>   An explicit value for the identity column in table 'sites_dynamic' can only be specified when a column list is used and IDENTITY_INSERT is ON.

Can anyone help me? I am new to this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [An explicit value for the identity column in table can only be specified when a column list is used and IDENTITY\_INSERT is ON SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2005437/an-explicit-value-for-the-identity-column-in-table-can-only-be-specified-when-a)

Answer (score 5):

When using `set identity_insert <tablename> on` your insert statement must include the columns list.

Here is the correct way to do it:

```
set identity_insert targetTable on

insert into targetTable (col1, col2 [, coln])
select col1, col2 [, coln]
from sourceTable

set identity_insert targetTable off
```

As commented by Nick.McDermaid - It's best practice to always include the columns list.

Comment: Might I add: You should _always_ include columns lists regardless!

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid You are absolutely correct. Edited that into my answer.