# How to copy only one row and paste it into that table

Tags: c#, winforms, sql-insert

I have a table *table_A*, it has ten rows, *id_Row* of table from 1 to 10. And I set *id_Row* is "Identity Increment = true" - Obligate. But now, I want to copy the 7th row => *table_A* will have 11 rows (and paste into this *table_A*). I wrote:

```
INSERT INTO table_A SELECT * FROM  table_A WHERE id_Row = '7'
```

But I got an error:

```
An explicit value for the identity column in table 'table_A' can only be specified when a column list is used and IDENTITY_INSERT is ON.
```

Can someone please let me know how to fix it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2005437/an-explicit-value-for-the-identity-column-in-table-can-only-be-specified-when-a/36309404
Check this one

Comment: Is this column a primary key?

Comment: you have map column explicitly ...

Comment: Like @Sheradil said take a look into that link, if you search your error in google you would get that as the first result ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: You could use [SEQUENCE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-sequence-transact-sql) object in order to generate consecutive numbers. When you need to insert arbitrary number, just don't generate number by SEQUENCE.

Comment: You need to use Update if the id_Row already exists i the database.

Comment: @JohnyL: yes `id_Row` is primary key

Comment: @jdweng: Yes, `id_Row` already exist, but i don't understand your opinion

Comment: SQL Server has both an UPDATE and an INSERT command.  Use UPDATE.

Answer (score 0):

You have two option:

> 1: Before Insert use this script (if `id_Row = '7'` does not exists in
>   `table_A`):

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT table_A  On

INSERT INTO table_A
SELECT * FROM  table_A WHERE id_Row = '7'

SET IDENTITY_INSERT table_A  Off
```

> 2: If `id_Row = '7'` exists in `table_A` use columns list explicitly

```
 INSERT INTO table_A 
 SELECT x,y,z,... FROM  table_A WHERE id_Row = '7'
```

Comment: `id_Row = '7'` exists in `table_A` and it has a lot of columns, so i don't want to have to type all the columns out manually. so, how can I do?